# laravel pagination is not working

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

wanna ask for pagination. Why my pagination is not working, when I click the 2nd number in pagination it tells `"NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php"` and the design is also just a number, cant render the design. I'm using Bootstrap 4.

Here's my controller

```
function searchuser(Request $req){

    if($req->has('searchuserr')){
        $data = User::where('name','like','%'.$req->input('searchuserr').'%')->select('name','email','status', 'pp', 'gender')->orderBy('name')->paginate(4);
        $data->setPath($req->url()."?search=".$req->searchuserr);
        return view('Users.searchuser')->with('data', $data);
    }
    else{
        return redirect('Users.searchuser');
    }
}
```

and my routes for these function

```
Route::get('/searchuserpage', ['uses'=>'searchController@searchuser']);
```

in my pages i wrote this `{{data->links()}}`

Comment: At a first good guess, I'd say the link you put into the output is wrong.

Comment: didnt get it ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making mistake in your setPath() method. The query you are using is "searchuserr" and you added "search" for pagination.

**Your code**

```
$data->setPath($req->url()."?search=".$req->searchuserr);
```

**The code should be**

```
$data->setPath($req->url()."?searchuserr=".$req->searchuserr);
```

Note: 
You are might also making mistake on else condition.

```
return redirect('Users.searchuser');
```